# No inserts on mixer but need to use sonic exciter in the chain. How do I do it?

Tags: behringer

Oh dear...I advised some equipment for a friend for his podcasting:

- Behringer SX3040 Stereo Sound Enhancement Processor
- Behringer MIC2200 Component Rack
- Behringer MDX4600 4-Channel Expander/Gate/Compressor/ Peak Limiter
- Behringer QX1204USB 12-Channel Mixer

He purchased the items...Problem I now have is the mixer has no insert's !

The above is the same equipment list as I have accept the mixer, mine has inserts.
I run a mic to the 2200 pre amp, pre amp to 4600, 4600 to mixer channel input then run my y cable from that channel insert to sx3040

How can I help this guy get his sx3040 into the chain properly without an insert on his mixer channel???

I have only ever used mixers with an insert so don't know how to get over the problem other than suggest he sells it and buys another mixer with inserts (Feeling bad) :- (

Comment: um, downvote? Hmm…seems on topic to me.

Comment: Is the SX3040 to be used only to process the sound of the microphone?

Answer (score 1):

You only have two other options if you don't have inserts.  You can send out on an aux channel and feed it back as another input.  This may work in this case if you don't need stereo, but it will be a bit ugly.  You would need to left and right pan each channel set and then use the 4 channels of AUX (1L, 1R, 2L, 2R) and returns to handle it.  You'll need to double check the manual to see if it supports the needed routing to make it happen though.

The other option is to do your signal processing before getting to the board.  This will require external pre-amps though because you will need to get the signal up to line level before you can start it down the processing chain.  Then the line level input would go in to the board.

If you didn't need to work per channel, then you could feed out through the tape out or do the processing after the final output from the board.

Really, the proper way is a board with inserts though if you want to do per channel effects.